# Assign a matrix to an [] array Matrix in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Initial value

```
    Matrix<float>[] output_measurement = new Matrix<float>[25];
    Matrix <float> output_measurement_temp= new Matrix<float>(6, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
     {

     output_measurement[i] = new Matrix<float>(6, 1);         
     }
```

Assign Value

```
    for (int i =0;i<25;i++)
    {
     for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
     {
      if (measure1joint[j, 0] != 10f)
      {
     output_measurement_temp[j, 0] = measure1joint[j, 0];
     output_measurement_temp[j + 3,0] = 0f;// set velocity =0                                    
      }
     }
     output_measurement[i]=output_measurement_temp;// Problem here!
    }
```

My problem is: every time when the value of Maitrix "output_measurement_temp" are changed, all of assigned value in array Matrix changed together to the new updated output_measurement_temp. For example:

First time: output_measurement_temp =0 , output_measurement[0]= **0**

Second time:output_measurement_temp =1 , output_measurement[0]= **1**,output_measurement[1]=1

Can anyone help me to explain why it happened.

Edit: If I reset the value of output_measurement_temp before I assign the new value to it, the value of assigned value in "output_measurement" will not change anymore. But I dont know why it can help

```
  output_measurement_temp = new Matrix<float>(6, 1);
       for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
       {some code...}
```

Comment: I found a way to solve problem is: every time before I assign the new value to "output_measurement_temp". I need to re initial it to 0. I still can not explain why it can help.

output_measurement_temp = new Matrix<float>(6, 1);

for (int j =0; j<3; j++)
{some code....}

Comment: I think your `Matrix<X>` type is a `class` type? When you reuse the same `new Matrix<float>(6, 1)` over and over again, this happens. Because each time you assign it to a new entry in the array, all that is assigned is a ___reference___ to that same instance. The entire object is not copied, or cloned, just the "reference" is copied and put into the array. And when you modify the instance with `xxx[3, 0] = yyy;` (indexer access) that affects every array entry which holds a reference to this instance.

Comment: Where is `Matrix<>` defined? Is it a `class` or a `struct` you wrote yourself, or a you using something like [`Extreme.Mathematics.Generic.Matrix<T>`](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/Documentation/Reference/Extreme.Mathematics.Generic.Matrix(T).aspx)?

Comment: Dear Jeppe Stig Nielsen,
Thank you for your answer.
Matrix is a class borrowed from Emgu.CV library. I think you point out problem exactly, which is similar to Kim.L by below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix in C# is a reference type but bot a value type.When you change the "output_measurement_temp" and assign it to output_measurement[i],you just assign reference of "output_measurement_temp" to output_measurement[i] but not value of output_measurement_temp in fact.And every time the line you tag as "probleam here" works the same.

Comment: You've initialized all the 25 elements of output_measurement,and your codes don't need a temporary variable.

Comment: our are right, I dont need to use the temporary variable. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used C# or Java for a long time, so I hope you may excuse any mistakes I may make here. From what you are describing, it looks like the `output_measurement_temp` doesn't store the `Matrix`, but it contains the address to the location where the value for the `Matrix` stores in the memory. So each time you pass a new value to `output_measure_temp`, it uses the address on the `output_measurement_temp` and find the location in memory and change the values to what you tell it to store.

In the second case, when you declare a `new` you assign a new location in the memory to store the new value.

[check this out](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/arrays-in-C-Sharp-language/)

Comment: I combine your intuitive explanation with the Joeries answer above. Matrix in C# is a reference, so the output_measurement_temp is worked as an address. At the beginning, everytime, I changed the value in the address, but not the address. And all the entries of the output_measurement always go to the same address to get the only one value inside it.
In second case, every entry of  output_measurement will point to different addresses to get different values.Thank you, it is clear for me now :D.